# Careers bug: seeing login page after logging in

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, login

Just now, I randomly clicked the Employer "Search CVs" button from the Careers home page while logged out. After being greeted with a employer login page, I then proceeded to click the login link at the top right hand corner of the page (the info bar: where it says about & faq). This brought me to the page whose URL is:

> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=/employer

Next, I entered my OpenID and logged in as a CV-creator. After logging in, I was redirected to the employer login page, as the above URL shows in the "returnurl" parameter.

---

### Basically:

**To reproduce**:

- Start on the home page, signed out
- Click "Search CVs" button under the Employers heading on the right side of the page
- After being taken to a log in page, click "login" in the info bar at the top
- Login

**Expected**: to be redirected to the CV home page or to be given a "already logged in" message

**Actual results**: taken to employer login page while being already logged in as a CV-creator

It's not a big bug, but it's most likely an easy fix.